# updatedb : File size limit exceeded (18.04 LTS)

Tags: locate, updatedb

Whenever I run a command :

```
updatedb
```

I get the message :

```
File size limit exceeded (core dumped)
```

Why is that ?

I know that **locate** command utilizes a database created by a related utility, **updatedb**. Most Linux systems run this automatically once a day. However, you can update it at any time by just running **updatedb** from the command line as the root user.

update :

```
root@node1:~# ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) 2001
pending signals                 (-i) 23227
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 23227
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `ulimit -a`? You have probably hit the file size limit defined in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: @Matigo  thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file size is limited to `2001` blocks.

As per this [tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/file-size-limit-exceeded-error-under-linux-and-solution/) increase it using:

```
vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

By comparison my system which is stock has:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127556
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127556
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However why does "root" user has the limits that were set to a user "student" ? 

As a student I did "sudo -i" to become a root user and the limits still applied to root :/

Comment: As a student you wouldn't normally have `sudo` powers? But regardless try using `sudo updatedb`. That is the way I run it manually. Finally if a system administrator has broken `locate` command for you then using `find` is an alternative.